# Is it possible to instrument classes from java.* package

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

Is it possible to instrument classes of the `java.*` packages?

I would like to replace method body of the `java.awt.print.PrinterJob.printDialog(PrintRequestAttributeSet)` to make it always return `true`.

When defining a new class withing `java.*`, I am getting `SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.awt.print`. Obviously it happens because I am trying to define class with `java.` in the package's name.

So is there a way to bypass this security check or solve this problem differently?

P.S I also tried to redefine `java.awt.printerjob` system property in order to use my own implementation of `PrinterJob`. But I failed because my class was not found. I didn't manage to find the actual `PrinterJob`'s class loader to load my class.

```
@Test public void testInstrumentationOfJavaClasses() throws Exception
{
    // replace printDialog(attrs) so that it always returns true
    String typeName = "java.awt.print.PrinterJob";
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    MethodReplacer methodReplacer = new MethodReplacer(cw, "printDialog", "(Ljavax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttributeSet;)Z");
    ClassReader classReader = createClassReader(typeName);
    classReader.accept(methodReplacer, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
    loadClass(cw.toByteArray(), typeName);

    // the actual call of PrinterJob which as I expect to always return "true"
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(PRINTABLE);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printerSettings = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    if (printJob.printDialog(printerSettings))
        printJob.print(printerSettings);
}

public static class MethodReplacer extends ClassVisitor implements Opcodes
{
    private final String methodName;
    private final String methodDefenition;

    public MethodReplacer(ClassVisitor classVisitor, String methodName, String methodDescr)
    {
        super(ASM5, classVisitor);
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.methodDefenition = methodDescr;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions)
    {
        if (methodName.equals(name) && methodDefenition.equals(desc))
        {
            System.out.println("visitMethod(" + name + ")");
            MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, name, desc, null, new String[]{"java/awt/HeadlessException"});
            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
            mv.visitInsn(IRETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
            return mv;
        }
        return super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    }
}

private static Class loadClass(byte[] bytecode, String typeName) throws Exception
{
    ClassLoader baseClassLoader = TestPrint.class.getClassLoader();

    Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[]{String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class};
    Method m = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", types);
    m.setAccessible(true);

    Object[] args = new Object[]{null, bytecode, 0, bytecode.length};
    Class definedClass = (Class<?>) m.invoke(baseClassLoader, args);
    return definedClass;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Java `Instrumentation` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). You can invade the `java.*` namespace in different ways:

1. Create new classes with the `java.*` prefix, bundle those files into a *jar* and append those classes to the bootstrap class loader. Those classes are then available from the bootstrap class loader (i.e. *globally*).
2. Register a `ClassFileTransformer` that is invoked when a class is loaded. For some bootstrap classes, this allows to alter a class's byte code before the class is loaded. It is important that these classes are not required for setting up the agent. For *AWT* classes, this should work fine.
3. Redefine classes of the `java.*` namespace. The instrumentation API allows for a retransformation / redefinition of some classes even after they are loaded.

I wrote a library called [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) that intends to make the use of such instrumentation easier if you want to avoid writing a Java agent manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this API will help me. I will try it out and accept your answer. Or ask for some help if something goes wrong =)

Comment: I registered ClassFileTransformer and successfully redefined PrinterJob.getPrinterJob to make it return MyPrinterJob.
As you said I cannot use PrinterJob before redefining it in agent so I'd like to load MyPrinterJob class from the main library (the one I launch agent from).
My ASM code calls Class.forName("my.print.MyPrinterJob").newInstance() but java.lang.ClassNotFoundException occurs.
Is it possible to access main's project ClassLoader?

Comment: The ClassFileTransformer gives access to the instrumented class's class loader. A Java agent is always loaded by the system class loader.

Comment: What if I load agent by VirtualMachine.attach(pid).loadAgent(jarPath, "") ?

Comment: Same. It is going to be executed by the target machine's system class loader.

Comment: Ok I will try and create a small "hello world" app to check if I've missed something